# Solve sound ranging function with fsolve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, solver

I am trying to solve the sound ranging problem described in this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_ranging#cite_note-old-5

I have a Matlab function like this:

```
function [f]=equation1(x)
c = 330 ;%speed of sound meters per second 
% unknown variable : 
% r1 => x(1) 
% theta => x(2)

time2 = 0.455; % Microphone 1 to Microphone 2 time delay
time3 = 0.606; % Microphone 1 to Microphone 3 time delay
% gives : 
r2 = 150 %time2*c;
r3 = 200 %time3*c; 

r4 = 1267.9; % Distance from Microphone 2 to Microphone 3
r5 = 499.1; % Distance from Microphone 1 to Microphone 3

phi = 16.177; % Angle between Microphone 1 and Microphone 2 measured from Microphone 3

f(1)= -(x(1) + r2)^2 + (x(1)+r3)^2 +r4^2 -2*(x(1)+r3)*r4*cosd(x(2));
f(2)= - x(1)^2  + (x(1)+r3)^2  + r5^2 - 2*(x(1)+r3)*r5*cosd(x(2)-phi);
end
```

When I run `[x,feval]=fsolve(@equation1,[100 10])`, the code returns  results `x= 581.4332  -31.8492`. But in the example `r1` is 1621 meters. I don't see my error in this program.

Comment: Could you provide more information on what part of the article you get your equations from?

Comment: just below the Figure 2: Example of An Artillery Location Problem.  [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/6/e/36e9d6ad890f0bead47e51aeeaface26.png) and [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/f/8/2f8762bc5e481fb11064e71ae6d6c47e.png)

Answer (score 2):

You swapped the values of `r4` and `r5`, it should be:

```
r4 = 499.1; % Distance from Microphone 2 to Microphone 3
r5 = 1267.9; % Distance from Microphone 1 to Microphone 3
```

Also, the output that the console is returning is the value of `feval`, not `x`. With the correct values of `r4` and `r5`, I displayed the correct answer like this:

```
[x,feval]=fsolve(@equation1,[100 10]);
disp(x);
```

which outputs

```
1.0e+03 *

1.6230    0.0764
```

as expected.